# Compile gtk library in combination with other libraries using a Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gtk

I'm having troubles compiling the gtk library with my c++ program. I have gtk installed and my program is working when using terminal command like:

```
gcc -Wall -g helloworld.c -o helloworld `gtk-config --cflags` \
    `gtk-config --libs`
```

But i need it to compile with some other libraries to, so i have a Makefile, but don't know how to make it also compile the gtk libraries.

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -fPIC -Wextra -Werror -lpthread -pthread # for Linux and other gcc systems
OP=$(CFLAGS)  
CC=g++  #for Linux

# compilation rule for general cases
.o :
    $(CC) $(OP) -o $@ $? -lm
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(OP) $<     

SWEOBJ = swedate.o swehouse.o swejpl.o swemmoon.o swemplan.o swepcalc.o sweph.o\
    swepdate.o swephlib.o swecl.o swehel.o

astrogtk: astrogtk.o libswe.a
    $(CC) $(OP) -I/home/arjan/astroproject -o astrogtk astrogtk.o -L. -lswe -lm -ldl 

swemini: swemini.o libswe.a
    $(CC) $(OP) -o swemini swemini.o -L. -lswe -lm

# create an archive and a dynamic link libary fro SwissEph
# a user of this library will inlcude swephexp.h  and link with -lswe

libswe.a: $(SWEOBJ)
    ar r libswe.a   $(SWEOBJ)

libswe.so: $(SWEOBJ)
    $(CC) -shared -o libswe.so $(SWEOBJ)

clean:
    rm -f *.o astrogtk libswe*

###
swecl.o: swejpl.h sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
sweclips.o: sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h
swedate.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swehel.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swehouse.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h swephlib.h swehouse.h
swejpl.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swejpl.h
swemini.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
swemmoon.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
swemplan.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h swemptab.h
swepcalc.o: swepcalc.h swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h
sweph.o: swejpl.h sweodef.h swephexp.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
swephlib.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h sweph.h swephlib.h
astrogtk.o: swephexp.h sweodef.h swedll.h astromath.h
```

I tried adding the gtk line on different locations inside the Makefile

`gtk-config --cflags gtk-config --libs`

But where ever i try to place it, it just says it can't find the gtk header file...

```
astrogtk.cpp:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'astrogtk.o' failed
make: *** [astrogtk.o] Error 1
```

So whats the solution for compiling the gtk library, using this makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `gtk-config --cflags` to your `CFLAGS`. Then add `gtk-config --libs` to your libraries, right next to those `-lswe -lm -ldl`

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around, I found this command on [this site here](https://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/firstprograms/),
which solved my compiling issues with c++ on Arch :

```
$ gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

There might be the need to adapt the command to your GTK version.

Using VS code as an IDE has helped a lot in importing libraries.